# AT91 USB-Serial issues -> Communication not possible

Tags: usbserial

Good day

I've been dealing with this problems for some times.

A board, utilizing the **AT91 Chipset** from Microchip, has a direct USB Port. This USB Port is used for Debugging, setting SN and all the other configurations on this board.

I power on the board, I plug in the USB cable and I will get a COM Port assigned. Normally we have this port on COM6 to keep the process streamlined.

Out of nowhere, this communication simply stopps. I still have the COM Port. I can still open the port up in a terminal (TeraTerm). But I cannot get an answer. If I enable Echo, I get a noticible delay for my input, which doesnt happen, if its working perfectly.

**Summary:**

- Win7 worked great, update to Win10 did bring out the issue. But I've tried using a new Win7 machine and still getting the same issue.
- We might suspect windows updates. It gets more frequent since couple months
- It can stop from one moment to the other (but the board still works perfectly on another working computer
- Working & Not working shows to use the following driver: usbser.sys 10.0.19041.2130
- HW ID USB\VID_1FC5&PID_0001
- Works 100% of the time on Linux (Not a solution for our use case)

Any pointers to how I can debug this and find the issue?
Maybe a custom inf driver?

**I've tried:**

- Uninstalled the device, deleting the driver
- Tried installing some driver from Microchip in regards to AT91, but most wont work
- Complete Powerdown of the system (pulled the plug) and restartet

**Workaround:**
In the past, I've always managed to find a workaround with one of the following two:
**- ZADIG and forced a new USB CDC driver onto this device

- Windows Recovery tool to a date which everything worked perfectly**
  But currently **only the recovery is dooing its job**. But it takes between 30-60min and it can happen within hours again.

Many thanks.